# Accessing a return value within a sql query using connection string

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure, msnodesqlv8

I am connecting to a database using mssqlnodev8 connection string and I cannot access the result outside the block of code where I make the query. Is there a way for me to return the value that I like outside the query? This is a helper function that I use to transform one value to another using a database.

````
const transformTable = async (field, value) => {
    try {
        field = field.replace("'","''");
        if (typeof value !== 'boolean' ){
            value = value.replace("'","''");
        }
        const query = `SELECT XXX FROM XXXTable WHERE fieldName = '${field}' AND adpName = '${value}'`;
        //set the variable that I want to return with this function
        let test = '';
        //This is where I make the connection using a connection string
        await sql.query(connectionString, query, (err, info) => {
            if (err){
                console.log(err)
                return
            }
            //I want to set the INFO to the test variable that I created outside of this block 
            test = info
        })
        //I want to return the value of the variable that I set from info
        console.log(test, 'test info')
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}```
````

Comment: You've tagged your question mysql, but you reference mssqlnodev8, which is a Node.js connector for Microsoft SQL Server. Can you please clarify which database you are using? Run this query: `SELECT @@version;` and tell us what it returns.

Comment: It's Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM)

Comment: I've edited the tags. Using correct tags is import for you, because it will help get attention from the people who are best able to answer your question. For example, I know mysql very well, but I don't use Azure or Microsoft SQL Server, so I'm not qualified to answer your question. Some other people are, but they wouldn't have known to look at your question if it was mis-tagged.